# Electron, how to make a window slide from offscreen? (like the notifications center)

Tags: macos, electron

I'd like to achieve the same opening/closing animations as macOS' notifications center, basically having it slide from a side.

Is it possible to do this using electron?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think it is possible. Electron has everything you need for it:

- A [Frameless Window](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/frameless-window.md) is probably the way to go for this.
- [`win.setPosition(x, y[, animate])`](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/browser-window.md#winsetpositionx-y-animate), [`win.setSize(width, height[, animate])`](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/browser-window.md#winsetsizewidth-height-animate), [`win.hide()`](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/browser-window.md#winhide) and [`win.show()`](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/browser-window.md#winshow) is all you need to animate the window
- [`screen`](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/screen.md) and [`Display`](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/structures/display.md) will help you put the window in the correct position

**Initial state:**

- Place window at the side of the screen
- Set to smallest possible width
- Hidden

**Opening:**

1. Show window
2. Increase width and change position towards center of the screen until the window reaches the desired size

**Closing:**

1. Decrease width and change position towards side of the screen
2. Hide window when side is reached

The content of the window is then just CSS and JS magic, to make it look good.

Comment: Sounds like a decent workaround, but I can't pass negative values to `win.setPosition` and I can't shrink the window more than a certain amount (~100px)

Comment: Actually it looks like I can shrink it to any amount I like, but only via the API.

Answer (score -5):

Check out css animations [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp)

You can position elements off screen with css and animate them in with css

No javascript required.